Symbol Already Declared Error in Tanstack-Router using File based routing
I'm getting the following error
dev-ui-x-1  |   ✘ [ERROR] The symbol "IntelIocTypeSummaryRoute" has already been declared
dev-ui-x-1  | 
dev-ui-x-1  |     src/routeTree.gen.ts:50:6:
dev-ui-x-1  |       50 │ const IntelIocTypeSummaryRoute = IntelIocTypeSummaryImport.update({
dev-ui-x-1  |          ╵       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
dev-ui-x-1  | 
dev-ui-x-1  |   The symbol "IntelIocTypeSummaryRoute" was originally declared here:
dev-ui-x-1  | 
dev-ui-x-1  |     src/routeTree.gen.ts:45:6:
dev-ui-x-1  |       45 │ const IntelIocTypeSummaryRoute = IntelIocTypeSummaryImport.update({
dev-ui-x-1  |          ╵       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

My route folder structure looks like this
routes
├── __root.tsx
├── index.tsx
├── user.tsx
└── intel
    └── $iocType
        └── summary
            └── index.tsx

The route file in question is defined as
import {createFileRoute} from "@tanstack/react-router";
import {Summary} from "@/pages/intel/summary.tsx";
import {AnimatedRouteWrapper} from "@/routes/__root.tsx";

export const Route = createFileRoute('/intel/$iocType/summary')({
    component: () => <AnimatedRouteWrapper><Summary/></AnimatedRouteWrapper>,
    validateSearch: (search) => ({
        q: decodeURIComponent(search.q as string)
    })
})

And my summary page is super simple, like this
import {useParams, useSearch} from "@tanstack/react-router";

export const Summary = () => {
    const {iocType} = useParams({from: "/intel/$iocType/summary"})
    const {q} = useSearch({from: "/intel/$iocType/summary"})

    return <div>Summary for {iocType} with query {q}</div>;
}

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. That route isn't defined anywhere else other than in routes/intel/$iocType/summary/index.tsx. I tried having the file be summary.tsx (and not having the folder summary), but I had the same error. I've deleted the gen'd routeTree file (I'm using Vite, with plugins: [TanStackRouterVite(), react()], in my vite config)
Anybody have any thoughts? Hopefully this is just me not understanding something simple!
